# python modules in gcloud deployment manager template

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-deployment-manager

Is it possible to use modules installed via python pip in gcloud deployment manager templates (python templates, not jinja)?

I have only being able to find reference of how to import .py files through a deployment manager schema file. e.g.

app.py.schema

```
info:
title: app
author: me
description: this is a description

imports:
- path: helper.py
```

i.e. i can only import a single .py at a time, so not useful for importing pip modules.

this [link](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/configuration/templates/import-python-libraries) explains that to use libraries that is not explicitly supported we need to import the full library source. Although it does not mention if this full library source can actually be a pip module, or is it only referring to single .py files.

The module i'm trying to use inside my python templates is `netaddr` for manipulating ip address and subnets.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you are looking for it not possible, you cannot install module using pip with interacting the the API, unless if you want to import the whole netaddr module as source code in your *.yaml config file (by adding the path for all the files related to the module) then importing which function your *.py file as Google mention in the documentation some library are supported, even with that some sys and network call will be rejected, you may think about using [template_module](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/template_modules)

---

#### Original Answer:

Yes, you can check the link [Here](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/step-by-step-guide/using-multiple-templates#create_the_configuration) for importing multiple python files and using multiple templates.

Comment: The link you shared show how to import python templates, not python module. I want to use a python module like `netaddr` in my python template.

Comment: what you are looking for it not possible, you cannot install module using pip with interacting the the API, unless if you want to import the whole netaddr module as source code in your *.yaml config file (by adding the path for all the files related to the module)  then importing which function your *.py file as Google mention in the documentation some library are supported, even with that some sys and network call will be rejected, you may think about using [template_module](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/tree/master/examples/v2/template_modules)

Comment: Thanks @Alioua, if you want to post that as the answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Thank you @John no worry :)

Comment: @JohnS can you accept the answer now? the comment has been moved into the answer section.